# Expected a value of type '(BuildContext, AnimalModelType<Animal>) => void', but got one of type '(BuildContext, DogsViewModel) => void'

Tags: flutter, dart

I created an Animal More Button that has 2 options. The first option is `eat` which applies to all animals and the second option only applies to a specific animal, in this example is `bark`. Clicking eat will print eat in the console as expected, but clicking bark results in this error in the console.

After debugging, `option.callback(context, animalModel)` inside `_onSelected(BuildContext context, AnimalMoreButtonOption option` returns this error.

**Console**

```
errors.dart:251 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Expected a value of type '(BuildContext, AnimalModelType<Animal>) => void', but got one of type '(BuildContext, DogsViewModel) => void'
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:251:49)
    at Object.castError (errors.dart:84:3)
    at Object.cast [as as] (operations.dart:452:10)
    at dart.FunctionType.new.as (types.dart:829:12)
    at _onSelected (main.dart:62:20)
    at _onSelected.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
    at AnimalMoreButton.new.[_onSelected] (main.dart:60:19)
    at main.dart:69:31
    at popup_menu.dart:1144:28
    at _RootZone.runUnary (zone.dart:1685:54)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleValue (future_impl.dart:159:18)
    at handleValueCallback (future_impl.dart:766:44)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (future_impl.dart:795:13)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (future_impl.dart:601:5)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (future_impl.dart:639:7)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40:11)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
    at async_patch.dart:166:15
```

I don't understand why the type is wrong in the callback. Because `DogsViewModel` implements `AnimalModelType<Dog>` and `Dog` extends `Animal`. `AnimalModelType` is a generic class `AnimalModelType<TAnimal extends Animal>`.

`AnimalMoreButton` is a class that has option `eat` for all animals, it takes `additionalOptions` param for specific animal options. In this case `MenuButton<AnimalMoreButtonOption>` has 2 options of type `MenuOption<AnimalMoreButtonOption<AnimalModelType>>` and `MenuOption<AnimalMoreButtonOption<DogsViewModel>>`.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MenuButton<AnimalMoreButtonOption>(
      label: 'more',
      onSelected: (option) => _onSelected(context, option),
      options: [
        MenuOption<AnimalMoreButtonOption<AnimalModelType>>(
          value: AnimalMoreButtonOption.eat,
          label: 'eat',
        ),
        // ...additionalOptions,
        // MenuOption<AnimalMoreButtonOption<DogsViewModel>>(
        //   value:
        //     AnimalMoreButtonOption((context, model) => _bark(context, model)),
        //   label: 'bark',
        // ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Animal More Button',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Animal More Button'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final model = DogsViewModel();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Provider(
        create: (BuildContext context) => model,
        child: Center(
          child: AnimalMoreButton<DogsViewModel>(
            additionalOptions: model.getAdditionalMoreButtonOptions(context),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimalMoreButton<T extends AnimalModelType> extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnimalMoreButton({this.additionalOptions = const [], Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  /// Additional options to display in the popup menu
  final List<MenuOption<AnimalMoreButtonOption>> additionalOptions;

  void _onSelected(BuildContext context, AnimalMoreButtonOption option) async {
    final animalModel = context.read<T>();
    option.callback(context, animalModel);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MenuButton<AnimalMoreButtonOption>(
      label: 'more',
      onSelected: (option) => _onSelected(context, option),
      options: [
        MenuOption<AnimalMoreButtonOption>(
          value: AnimalMoreButtonOption.eat,
          label: 'eat',
        ),
        ...additionalOptions,
      ],
    );
  }
}

class AnimalMoreButtonOption<T extends AnimalModelType> {
  const AnimalMoreButtonOption(this.callback);

  final void Function(BuildContext context, T animalModel) callback;

  static final eat = AnimalMoreButtonOption((context, animalModel) {
    print('eat');
  });
}

abstract class AnimalModelType<TAnimal extends Animal> {
  AnimalModelType();

  List<MenuOption<AnimalMoreButtonOption<AnimalModelType>>>
      getAdditionalMoreButtonOptions(BuildContext context) => [];
}

class Animal {
  const Animal({
    required this.name,
  });

  final String name;
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  const Dog({
    required String name,
  }) : super(name: name);
}

class DogsViewModel implements AnimalModelType<Dog> {
  @override
  List<MenuOption<AnimalMoreButtonOption<DogsViewModel>>>
  getAdditionalMoreButtonOptions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      MenuOption(
        value:
            AnimalMoreButtonOption((context, model) => _bark(context, model)),
        label: 'bark',
      ),
    ];
  }

  void _bark(BuildContext context, DogsViewModel model) {
    print('bark');
  }
}

class MenuOption<T> extends Equatable {
  const MenuOption({
    required this.value,
    required this.label,
  });
  final T value;
  final String label;

  @override
  List<T> get props => [value];
}

class MenuButton<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuButton({
    required this.label,
    required this.options,
    this.onSelected,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String label;
  final List<MenuOption<T>> options;
  final void Function(T)? onSelected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton<T>(
      onSelected: onSelected,
      itemBuilder: (_) => options
          .map(
            (option) => PopupMenuItem(
              value: option.value,
              child: Builder(builder: (buildContext) {
                return Text(
                  option.label,
                );
              }),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      child: Text(
            label,
          ),
    );
  }
}
```